# How to retrive array using local Storage

Tags: ionic3, local-storage, angular5

[image: cartItem have 2 values but showing just one]In above picture cartItem have 2 values but showing just one.I am using localStorage in angular 5. i have multiple values which i have to store in array and then show on other page. Its Ecommerce application.i am storing data in array in localStorage but the problem is that when i get value in other component it show one least value. for example if i have 5 values(id) like [33,44,55,66,77] it show the output for just 4 values . i don't know what is the problem. Any help would be appreciated. my code is as follow.

```
addToCart(index) {debugger;
    this.added=true;
    this.dynamicArray.push(index);
    localStorage.setItem('cartItem', JSON.stringify(this.dynamicArray));
    this.toasterService.Success('Item Added Successfully')
    return true;
  }
```

and in other component i am receiving as

```
let id= localStorage.getItem('cartItem');
     if (id != null) {
      this.getProductDeatilForCart(id);
    }
    localStorage.removeItem('cartItem')
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by myself. Actually problem was that it was not judging 0 index of array. so i use JSON.parse library and it works for me perfactly. code is as follow.

```
let id =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));   
    if (id != null) {
      this.getProductDeatilForCart(id);
    }
```